# I am trying to make an a.i music video with 'video killed the radio star' collab book and i get this error:

Tags: python

https://colab.research.google.com/github/dmarx/video-killed-the-radio-star/blob/main/Video_Killed_The_Radio_Star_Defusion.ipynb

I generated the init images fine, but when i try to run the variation generating cell, i get the below error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffP13.jpg

```
Fetching variations
1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-12a2c8f0bffb> in <module>
    153         tot_variations -= curr_variation_count  # only generate variations we still need
    154         for _ in range(tot_variations):
--> 155             img = get_variations_w_init(prompt, init_image, start_schedule=(1-image_consistency))[0]
    156             save_frame(
    157                 img,

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/autograd/grad_mode.py in decorate_context(*args, **kwargs)
     25         def decorate_context(*args, **kwargs):
     26             with self.clone():
---> 27                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
     28         return cast(F, decorate_context)
     29 

TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'image'
```

I am not a coder, i have no idea how to even begin going about rectifying this.

Comment: This is going to be really hard to debug without seeing your code or your inputs. I went ahead and looked at the notebook and you appear to be having an issue in the "Generating animation frames" portion.

Did you change any of the demo code?

Comment: hi mr hutch, no sir i did not edit anything and your correct, it's the animation frames cell/portion, i could try and get any portion of code needed to you i'm just extremely inexperienced, eager to adapt though if it becomes necessary. Thanks

Comment: can i save a collab book in it's present state and send to people, such as yourself?

Comment: here's more of the code, expanding the '3 frames' https://imgur.com/a/5Umt0NU maybe that will help.

Comment: more code https://imgur.com/a/avkME0W

Comment: Have you tried running each section starting from the top again? Have you tried using a different video url?

The problem is, you are running somebody else's code that you don't understand and then asking the community to debug. 

My advice would be to:
- set the whole notebook back to defaults
- verify you can run the default settings
- update the video url
- walk through each section step by step

Comment: Also, please avoid linking to images of code. If possible, copy/paste the relevant code and add it into the original question.